# How to connect Chatbot API with chat created by signalR in Asp.Net.Mvc web-application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, chat, chatbot

I have been searching for past 2 days but can't find answers or any useful information how to do it. In Asp.Net.Mvc web application I have to create chatbot which will give bot answers on client questions. Bot API is already created. Now I have to create a chat in which clients will get the answers from  bot API. I searched and found that chat can be created by signalR, but don't know how  post answers in signalR chat from Bot API. I don't even understand if I am searching correctly as I only found that the bot itself can be created by Microsoft Bot Framework, I don't need that,as I mention Bot API is already created. Any suggestions?
i would be very grateful for any help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Spend some time learning how to implement chat in SignalR before connecting it to your bot.  Your question is too vague for any other answer.  You have a bot API, but don't tell us what it is?  That isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a bot platform already made, there are several (dialogflow, watson, ...) you just have to integrate it into your BOT API for answers from the client or a web services, I hope it helps you, regards